# Ubuntu 16.04 lts Login Issue

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mount

One of my ubuntu user account faces a login issue where it is returned back to the login screen again after a black screen. But i can login to other user accounts successfully.
When i Login to console by click ctrl+alt+f6 , the user get logged in and it displays a message that the user has no mount permission and uuid doesnt match.

Please note that the above user is a sudo user, and i have encrypted my hard disk and the user was logging in suceesfully  before i was trying a shell script program in my laptop.

My project is in a critical stage and i have some files that must be backed up, I will appreciate your help very much.

Comment: When i tried ls comand in the home of the above user in console login, it shows an encrypted file as .desktop and readme.txt . the readme.txt tell me to use an ecryptfs command , but the above command doesnt work

Comment: The question is not really related to programming. As of that the question is off topic here and might be asked on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com) instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the reason why you're not be able to log in graphically is that graphical login usually tries to read/write in your home directory. that why you can still try to log in using a virtual console (Ctrl + Alt + F1) and work from there.

Using a Live CD instead should also work. You can mount your encrypted system partition from the Live CD, too. For example, you can run gnome-disk-utility on your Live CD and decrypt+mount your system partition from there graphically.

Also, watch out that the instructions in the linked tutorial assume that you are logged in as the user whose home you want to rescue. If you are logged in as another user (e.g. root), then replace the command

```
ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

by something like

```
ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase /home/[the-user-you-whose-home-you-want-to-rewrap]/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

or (on a Live CD) by something like

```
ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase /[wherever-you-temporarily-mounted-the-home-partition]/[the-user-you-whose-home-you-want-to-rewrap]/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```